# Error in deploying django website on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am deploying my django website in heroku with DATABASE = {} in django's setting.py file.
I am following all the steps of [heroku help](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#view-logs) and every command ran
 but some applicaton error is coming on running command-

heroku open

```
 (jango)dc@dc-comp-4:~/website$ heroku open
    Opening evening-waters-7886... done
    (jango)dc@dc-comp-4:~/website$ 
    (process:8176): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

and my heroku log status is-

```
dc@dc-comp-4:~/website$ heroku logs
2015-02-26T09:07:09.555685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:07:09.555087+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:07:17.890143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -`
2015-02-26T09:07:20.325197+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:07:21.184736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:07:21.202490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:07:27.250898+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:07:56.156898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=9a9781c5-57d6-43c2-8ca0-43df571804a0 fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T09:08:01.602067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=597a1c36-200e-4f8c-8dfe-b00d4d2cacee fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T09:08:03.737046+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=4d790108-6019-4fce-9d1e-10eafca9efc1 fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T09:27:54.099907+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e061461 by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:27:54.099907+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:27:54.255144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:28:05.720678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:28:06.984648+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:28:07.736542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:28:07.737796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:28:07.721050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:28:11.784672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:28:13.765503+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:28:14.689070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:28:14.702968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:28:18.234685+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:28:48.532426+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=a2b76940-91ea-4d2d-884e-0049bc707217 fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T09:32:01.295019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=7bf7ddc0-a04f-4f40-aade-f7a5116cf9f0 fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T09:34:29.437580+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE resource by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:34:29.437580+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:34:29.678932+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:34:33.288768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:34:35.045626+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:34:35.717937+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:34:35.729414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:39:47.384245+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:39:47.384245+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE resource by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:39:47.747151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:39:50.940581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:39:52.075160+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:39:52.716034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:39:52.716772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:39:52.705237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:39:56.910325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:39:58.335235+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:39:59.091134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:39:59.123230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:41:28.032235+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5e882c5 by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:41:28.032235+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:41:28.577676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:41:32.256825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:41:33.437334+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:41:34.121450+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:41:34.126557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:41:46.438295+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:42:04.929728+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=f16cebee-7c15-42d5-bba6-a4c85d0addaf fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T09:43:05.406941+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=9e4aa61d-073d-49d2-a696-606b4c965d51 fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T09:44:05.946147+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER resource by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:44:05.946147+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:44:06.133499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:44:09.806610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:44:11.203036+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:44:11.895235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:44:11.911573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:52:08.400443+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:52:30.139203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=2e818d74-a717-41d4-9050-3be25889eaed fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T09:58:07.383685+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate` by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T09:58:11.492711+00:00 heroku[run.3731]: Awaiting client
2015-02-26T09:58:11.520152+00:00 heroku[run.3731]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
2015-02-26T09:58:13.489900+00:00 heroku[run.3731]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:58:13.503789+00:00 heroku[run.3731]: State changed from up to complete
2015-02-26T09:58:11.931301+00:00 heroku[run.3731]: State changed from starting to up
2015-02-26T09:59:05.424832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:59:12.340999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:59:13.778095+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:59:14.428734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:59:14.437924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:59:14.438617+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T09:59:17.805847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T09:59:19.331755+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T09:59:20.010738+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T09:59:20.028996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T09:59:23.726010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=c2ba4a6d-1357-47a4-abee-78cfe3db7545 fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T10:04:06.912448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=5d21087f-d811-4685-964b-23acf24fd499 fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T10:29:10.000446+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `pip install gunicorn` by rahulsatal92@gmail.com
2015-02-26T10:29:13.833066+00:00 heroku[run.8299]: Awaiting client
2015-02-26T10:29:13.871544+00:00 heroku[run.8299]: Starting process with command `pip install gunicorn`
2015-02-26T10:29:14.121060+00:00 heroku[run.8299]: State changed from starting to up
2015-02-26T10:29:18.182526+00:00 heroku[run.8299]: Process exited with status 0
2015-02-26T10:29:18.195891+00:00 heroku[run.8299]: State changed from up to complete
2015-02-26T10:32:34.286827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=evening-waters-7886.herokuapp.com request_id=29508561-6c27-4ac6-a67d-7543fb87b385 fwd="14.139.240.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-26T10:36:58.977614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T10:37:02.450833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T10:37:03.717531+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T10:37:04.438957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T10:37:04.439393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T10:37:04.418361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T10:37:08.015347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T10:37:09.728762+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-02-26T10:37:10.601803+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-26T10:37:10.596391+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-02-26T11:21:32.653989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-26T11:21:36.340593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn website:app --log-file=-`
2015-02-26T11:23:39.380466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
dc@dc-comp-4:~/website$ ^C
```

plz help me out.

Answer (score 2):

> bash: gunicorn: command not found

The above error clearly mention that you don't have `gunicorn` on Heroku server

**How to install**

1. Install it using `pip install gunicorn` will clear the error.
2. Add gunicorn to your requirements.txt file

Comment: On running above command i get- Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gunicorn in /home/dc/.virtualenvs/jango/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

Comment: @RahulSatal Better way to debug, Can you log into heroku bash and run `pip freeze` to make sure `gunicorn` ? or Try `heroku run pip install gunicorn`

Comment: yes it contain gunicorn==17.5 and command-
heroku run pip install gunicorn  , is successfully installed

Comment: @RahulSatal No sir here, Can you paste the heroku logs again ?

Comment: I have updated my heroku logs in the question. Plz check it out

Comment: No actually I'm still seeing the gunicorn command not found. You said gunicorn installed successfully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71767/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-rahul-satal).

Comment: yes on running command- heroku run pip install gunicorn ,i get installed successfully

Answer (score 1):

You should install django-toolbelt ( you can do that by `pip install django-toolbelt`) and it will install gunicorn) after that you need to add it to your requirements.txt ( using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` ).

Let me explain like this .
Heroku looks at your file structure and searches two things :
an Procfile and a requirements.txt ( if you have a python project, if you have other projects the name of this file that represents the dependency for you project may have another name , but let's stick with python django ).

It user the content of the requirements.txt to see what it needs to install, if i want a certain library  it needs to pe in that requirements.txt ( heroku will install everything that it know it should install and it knows what it should install by looking at requirements.txt )

Then it looks at the Procfile ( this file tell it what it should run in order to start the project )

Now coming to your bug , you can write in that prof file the flowing things 
`web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT`

this means : start a web dyno , run the following command and use the port that is provided by the environment variable `$PORT`
This will start django as on localhost, with the test server, just to be sure it works. You should not use this in production, but for debugging is good.

If you can't get it to work with this it means that you have other problems not just the gunicorn missing.

In heroku tutorial there is a part that says :

> Next, install our application’s dependencies with pip. In this case, we will be installing django-toolbelt, which includes all of the packages we need:
>   Django (the web framework)
>   Gunicorn (WSGI server)
>   dj-database-url (a Django configuration helper)
>   dj-static (a Django static file server)

Paste your requirements.txt here so we can figure it out faster .

And for using Django on heroku use [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) .

Comment: The only solutions that works for me. Thank you so much for such a detailed response.