# Is it convinient to change the app build in django 1.7 to django 1.3 version

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, deployment, pythonanywhere

I have developed a django app in django 1.7 version with python 2.7 and want to deploy it in [python anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) with free version, but python anywhere does not support it-

[image]

But it only supports django 1.3 with python 2.7. So what changes i have to make to run my code in it with django 1.3.

Else if anybody is having any other option for django(1.7) app deployment plz suggest me.

Also i have deployed my django app(1.7) with 3rd option selected(python 2.7, django 1.7) then the output is - [link to my deployed app](http://chitraDhawle.pythonanywhere.com)

Comment: Heroku offers a free tier...

Comment: yes i had tried on heroku, but its not working there was some problem while deploying. its link is- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739598/error-in-deploying-django-website-on-heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here- you can actually install the version of Django that you want using a [virtualenv](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango)!

The commands to run from bash are just

```
mkvirtualenv Django17
pip install django==1.7
```

And then making sure that you set your virtualenv path correctly in your webapps tab! (in this case your path would be `/home/your-user-name/.virtualenvs/Django17/`)

[image: Setting your Virtualenv]

ie. You would have to set the virtualenv path as shown in the picture above

ps: on an unrelated issue to 1.7 vs 1.3, the reason that you are seeing the Django welcome page of the hello world/congrats on your first webapp variety is because that is the sample webapp that we have made for you.

You would need to correctly set up the paths to point to your source-code for your actual website to be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to install any version of Django in Pythonanywhere.

There is a link in Pythonanywhere wiki that provides detailed instructions to do it: [Wiki](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango)

Answer (score 2):

You can user [Heroku](http://heroku.com/), it works with that django you want or python or mostly anything you want, it has a free plan and you can make how many apps you want.

For your question ... to downgrade from django 1.7 to 1.3 ... there are too many thins to consider and we don't know what do you do on your project.

Or another option is [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), i experimented with this.

You can even user Amazon , if you make an account you can get 12 months free trial, 750 hours / month for free with one machine.

Comment: but i had tried on heroku, but its not working there was some problem while deploying. its link is- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739598/error-in-deploying-django-website-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: You should follow the excellent release notes, but reverse them.

Each release note will tell you what’s new in each version, and will also describe any backwards-incompatible changes made in that version.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/

But it is probably better find an alternative to pythonanywhere.